# Specifying pipe delimiter within PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, google-bigquery, gsutil

This is likely more a question for PowerShell than `bq`, but wondering if anyone's run into this before.

Trying to use `bq` to extract a table as a CSV to a GCP storage bucket, but I need the file to be pipe-delimited.

Except, I'm trying to call from within a PowerShell script, and PS tends to be over-zealous in interpreting pipes as pipeline designators.

```
bq extract --destination_format CSV --compression GZIP --field_delimiter "^|" --print_header "false" ([PROJECT_ID]:[DATASET].[TABLE]) (gs://[BUCKET]/[FILENAME])
```

I've tried `^`, `\` and `|` to try to escape the pipe, and it always errors out. Since `--print_header` is next in the command, the error comes out as

> '--print_header' is not recognized as an internal or external command

but that's a red herring as it catches ANY attribute that's next in line.

Comment: have you tried the back tick character to escape the pipe character?

Comment: Have you tried to start the command with a ampersand? Like `&bq extract etc` ?

Comment: No escaping should be required (i.e. `--field_delimiter "|"` should work just fine) unless `bq` is actually a batch script (`bq.cmd` or `bq.bat`). In that case you may need to run the command like this: `& cmd /c 'bq extract ... --field_delimiter "|" ...'`.

Answer (score 0):

The below statement should work:
& cmd /c "bq extract --destination_format CSV --compression GZIP --field_delimiter "^|" --print_header "false" ([PROJECT_ID]:[DATASET].[TABLE]) (gs://[BUCKET]/[FILENAME])"